# API works in browser but not in postman or app

Tags: android, laravel, api, postman

All the API's work in the browser but none of them is working in my android app and postman.

Status:
In postman and in my app, error code received  is:
500 Internal Server Error

Comment: add more details, how did you send request (body, headers,..)

Comment: Use a separate Middleware for your API. Alternatively, Laravel comes bundled with [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is csrf-token you can disabled it in

`App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

and add your routes name in this array

```
$except = [] array.
```

Comment: I don't want to disable csrf-token for all my routes. Is there any alternative?

Comment: you can use something like this  'api/v1/*'

Comment: i disabled my routes and also server configuration had an issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It could be that postman is missing some request headers, cookies or session data. You could look into using [Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en). It's a tool which records requests made from Google Chrome and clones them to your Postman history. From that history tab you can simply replay the request, which will be an exact clone. Maybe that'll resolve the 500 errors you're getting.